# C++ multiple inheritance private member conflict

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

My actual problem is a little more complicated and requires using template classes.
This is a simpler version of that.

I have two classes:

```
class A
{
public:
   float a() { return _value; }
private:
   float _value;
};

class B
{
public:
   float b() { return _value; }
private:
   float _value;
};

class AB : public A, public B
{
public:
   // a() should return A::_value ?
   // b() should return B::_value ?
}
```

Will there be any conflicts between the members `_value` from `A` and `B` if that member is private? It makes sense that there would not be such a conflict since `AB` has no knowledge of that member.

Comment: Sidenote: Class templates generate classes. There is no such thing as a template class.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Not true. A template class was originally the instantiation of a class template, now template class just means class template.

Comment: @curiousguy: "Was" is not "is". While I don't have an authoritative source handy, I did come across this comment in the [C++ Templates FAQ](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#phrase-order): *Note that the 1998 C++ standard used the terms "template class" and "template function" in some places, but this was corrected in the 2003 version.*

Comment: @MarceloCantos I recall that the 1997 C++ standard randomly used both terms. Usage of "template class" was discontinued as too confusing. This is even worse in French: class template = _template de classe_; template class = _classe issue de template_ (or _class templatée_ ?). Many French translation were wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the members were public, there would be no conflict. There would, however, be an ambiguity if you tried to access `_value` from `AB`'s scope (assuming `AB` inherits from `A` and `B`) without qualifying it somehow:

```
class A { public: float _value; };
class B { public: float _value; };
class AB : public A, public B {
public:
  void f() {
    std::cout << _value;    // Error: ambiguous reference
    std::cout << A::_value; // OK
  }
};
class AB2 : public A, public B {
public:
  using B::_value;
  void f() {
    std::cout << _value; // OK; resolves to B's version.
  }
};
```

Comment: Correct. But `_value` is **private** and is anyhow cannot be accessed directly from `AB` scope.

Comment: @Mahesh: but access control is applied long *after* name lookup, so this is an important point.

Comment: @Mahesh: The OP asked, "Will there be any conflicts … if that member is private?" My opening sentence answers both aspects of the question and makes it abundantly clear that I was well-aware of the point you make.

Answer (score 1):

There would not be any conflict and each subobject data member is different from the other. I believe AB is a class that inherits both A, B.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't forget to actually inherit from `A` and `B`.

That said, each of the member functions simply refers to the variable in its own class.  Neither `A::a()` nor `B::b()` are aware of the existence of the other, nor of the fact that they will be derived from, and are entirely distinct.

Therefore, if you change your code a little to be as follows:

```
class A {
    float value_;
  public:
    float& a() { return value_; } 
};

class B {
    float value_;
  public:
    float& b() { return value_; } 
};

struct AB : A, B {
} ab;
```

You will now find that after `ab.a() = 1; ab.b() = 2;`, despite `B::value_` being modified, `A::value_` is unchanged and `std::cout << ab.a();` prints 1.

That also said, you are probably running into issues specific to class templates; for example, you may not be realising that every instantiation of a class template comes with its own static variables.  (I'm not saying this is the case, just that it sounds like your problem is unrelated to what you posted.)